# what is difference between = and =~ operator in prometheus?

Tags: metrics, prometheus, prometheus-operator

What is the meaning of **=~** operator in prometheus metrics?

Can any help me what is the exact difference between = and =~ operator?

for ex .

```
process_cpu_seconds_total{instance="test"} 
process_cpu_seconds_total{instance=~"test"}
```

The results are different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"=~: Select labels that regex-match the provided string (or substring).

For example, this selects all http_requests_total time series for staging, testing, and development environments and HTTP methods other than GET."

```
http_requests_total{environment=~"staging|testing|development",method!="GET"}
```

Taken from the [Prometheus.io docs.](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#instant-vector-selectors)

Answer (score 2):

You should only use the `=~` operator when comparing to a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

**Example:**

This will match the exact string `test`:

```
process_cpu_seconds_total{instance="test"}
```

This will match the regular expression `test.*`. Which means the string `test` followed or not by other character(s).

```
process_cpu_seconds_total{instance=~"test.*"}
```